# webdriver: force browser do "forget" history+coockies

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, browser-cache, browser-history

I need to do this:

1. login as the main user (enter usr/pwd)
2. enable/disable something
3. logout from admin
4. login again as the main user
   At point 4 (login again) sometimes the application requires usr/pwd ( which is fine) but a few times, it logged in without them ( guess because of cookies)

Is there any way to force browsers ( ff/ie/chrome) to "don't" save any history or usr/pwd , etc? 
I'm using webdriver 2.41 ina a grid environment using TestNG and Java.

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called ensureCleanSession in the DesiredCapablity profile. For more details please visit this [official doc.](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities)

I have used this with IE alone. Please read through the doc for other browser supports.